# Linux tmp-like dir in home folder?

Tags: linux, home-directory, tmp

I'd like to make a folder in my GNU/Linux home directory that behaves somewhat like TMPDIR (usually /tmp or /var/tmp); that is, a folder that deletes its contents on reboot or after they've started gathering cobwebs. What's the best way to go about this?

Note that I *do not* want to simply *move* the tmp dir to home.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't "delete on reboot"; it only exists in RAM in the first place. Mount `tmpfs` to a directory under your home directory.

Comment: Is there supposed to be a `tmpfs` file in `/dev`? There's not one on my system. Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: `tmpfs` is a virtual filesystem, just like `proc` or `sysfs`. You can use the name directly without specifying a device file.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following in your user's crontab:

```
@reboot rm -rf /home/user/path/*
```